# not getting all the instances of the recurring series events by using Microsoft graph API ? why

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I create recurring events from `2022-09-19` date to `2022-11-30` every Monday

now I want to get all the list of instances within the specified date range and for that, I used this graph API

**Here eventId is the master event id of recurring series**

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/events/{eventId}/instances?startDateTime=2022-09-19T00:00:00&endDateTime=2022-11-30T23:59:59`

But it returns only the first 10 instances not all, what I am missing here.

Comment: Does the response contain @odata.nextLink? Maybe by default it returns only 10 records and you need to use paging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging

Comment: yes it has @odata.nextLink property and I can call it gain to get next but isn't there any way to get all instances at once and when I am limiting the page size by using /instances?$top=2 in URL it throwing an error

Comment: startDateTime and endDateTime are required so use top query like this https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/events/{eventId}/instances?startDateTime=2022-09-19T00:00:00&endDateTime=2022-11-30T23:59:59&$top=100

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly your problem but for some reason if I use the exact same data provided by graph api model of the series the last instance will be missing, thus I extend the range by a day:

```
<?php
$range = $event->getRecurrence()->getRange();
$start = urlencode($range->getStartDate()->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z'));
$end = urlencode($range->getEndDate()->modify("+1 day")->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z'));
$query = "/users/$user_id/events/$graph_id/instances?\$select=id&StartDateTime=$start&EndDateTime=$end";
```